# $U(n)$ and $SU(n)$ are connected smooth submanifold of $M_{n,n}(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, submanifold

How can I prove that $U_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $SU_n(\mathbb{C})$ are smooth submanifolds of $M_{n,n}(\mathbb{C})$ ?

I know that given the manifold $X$, $Y$ is a smooth submanifold of $X$ if $\forall k$ there exist $f=(f_1,...,f_d) \in C^ \infty(A_k) $ such that:

1. $A_k \cap Y = V(f_1,...,f_d)$
2. $J_f$ has rank= $d $

where $\{A_k\}_k$ is a cover of X and $V(f_1,...,f_d)=\{x \in A_k:f_1(x)=f_2(x)=...=f_d(x)=0\}$

but I don't know how to apply this definition.

Am I allowed to say that $U_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $SU_n(\mathbb{C})$ are subgroups of $M_{n,n}(\mathbb{C})$, which is a manifold and then they are submanifolds of $M_{n,n}(\mathbb{C})$?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Unitary matrices are described by the algebraic relation $A^\star A = I$. Differentiate it and show that it is nonsingular. Same goes for the special unitary group, which has the additional algebraic relation $\det A=1$.

Comment: @Giuseppe how non-singularity is linked to the concept of submanifold?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Cartan's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-subgroup_theorem), every closed subgroup of a Lie group is again a Lie group. And it is easy to check that both $U_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $SU_n(\mathbb{C})$ are closed subgroups of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Cartan's Theorem involves Lie Algebra so is it strictly necessary to know Lie Algebra in order to prove that they are closed subgroups?

Comment: The statement of the theorem is that every closed subgroup of a Lie group is a again a Lie group. **How** exactly does this involve Lie algebras? Yes, the *proof* of the theorem involves Lie algebras, but that's another matter. And, no, you don't need Lie algebras **at all** to prove that they are closed subgroups.